# the file couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined while trying to open SQLite3 Database

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift2

I am using the FMDB library to open sqlite 3 database files within my iOS app with the following code.

```
    //
//  DatabaseLoader.swift
//  Museum-App-iOS
//
//  Created by THOMAS NEEDHAM on 12/07/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 THOMAS NEEDHAM. All rights reserved.
//
//  This class uses the FMDB libary from https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb 
//  Which is licenced under the MIT Licence
//  Copyright (c) 2008-2014 Flying Meat Inc.

import Foundation
import UIKit

internal class DatabaseLoader: NSObject {

var resourcesFolder:NSURL
var path:String
var database:FMDatabase!

internal override init(){
    //resourcesFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    do{
            self.resourcesFolder = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("museumDB", ofType: "")!)
            self.path = try String(contentsOfURL: self.resourcesFolder)
            self.database = FMDatabase(path: self.path)
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        NSLog("%@", error.description)
        self.path = "ERROR"
        self.database = nil
    }
    super.init()
}

internal func openDatabase() -> Bool{
    // try to open the database
    if(!database.open()){
        NSLog("Database Not Opened")
        return false
    }
    else{
        NSLog("Database Opened Successfully YAY")
        //NSLog("DB Path %@", self.getDatabasePath())
        return true
    }

}

internal func closeDatabase() -> Bool{
    // try to close the database
    if(!database.close()){
        NSLog("Database Not Closed")
        return false
    }
    else{
        NSLog("Database Closed Successfully YAY")
        return true
    }
}

internal func queryDatabase(query: String) -> FMResultSet!{
    // try to open the database
    if(!openDatabase()){
        NSLog("Database could not be opened for queries")
        return nil
    }
    else{
        NSLog("Database opened for queries")
        // try to begin a transaction with the database
        if(!database.beginTransaction()){
            NSLog("Could not begin a database transaction")
            return nil
        }
        else{
            // try to query the database
            NSLog("Database transaction started succesfully")
            let results = database.executeQuery(query)
            if(results == nil){
            NSLog("Query Failed")
                return nil
            }
            else{
                // if the query was successful return the results
                NSLog("Query Successful")
                return results
            }
        }
    }
}

internal func getDatabasePath() -> NSString{
    return database.databasePath()!
}

func copyDatabase(){
    let storePath : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).last! // get the location of the documents directory
    let fileManager : NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager() // get the file manager
    var fileCopyError:NSError? = NSError(domain: "Local", code: 0, userInfo: nil) // create an error pointer
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath((storePath as String) + "/museumDB" as String) { // check if the database already exists
        NSLog("Copying Database")
        let defaultStorePath : NSString! = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("museumDB", ofType: "") // get the default location of the database when the app was first installed
        if((defaultStorePath) != nil) { // if the database exists within the original location
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(defaultStorePath as String, toPath: storePath as String)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                fileCopyError = error
            } // copy it to the documents folder
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog("Database Already Exists")
    }

}
}
```

The above code worked fine up until the swift 2 update earlier this week. Now the code crashes and gives me the following error.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 "The file “museumDB” couldn’t
>   be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be
>   determined."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/thomasneedham/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B60A965A-26C7-44C2-9643-0928BD6A2BBF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/70DADB9D-0027-4B8A-8FB8-7DF47B0963DB/Museum-App-iOS.app/museumDB}

I have tried googling but not found anything that helps me fix my problem. I am reasonably new to iOS so if you can also explain to me what the problem is and how your solution fixes the problem that would be extremely helpful for me to extend my knowledge.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code suggests that you have a text file in your bundle containing a path to the database. That's very curious. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Rob I don't that path points to the database file but i guess it is trying to open it as a text file

Comment: `self.path = String(contentsOfURL: self.resourcesFolder)` means "open up that file that `resourcesFolder` references and return the `String` value contents into the `path` variable".

Comment: aah i see now that damn swift 2 converter i wanted to convert the URL to a string how do i do that?

Comment: Use the `path` method. But why bother to take `pathForResource`, convert it to a `NSURL` and then convert it back to a path? See my answer for simpler alternative. Or just use `URLForResource` and then get the `path` from that.

Comment: BTW, I notice that `queryDatabase` begins a transaction, but never commits it. Make sure that if you use transactions that every "begin" is balanced by a "commit". If you're just selecting data, though, transactions are not generally necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is getting the path to `museumDB` in the bundle, converting that to a `NSURL`, loading the contents of the file that URL references into a `String` variable, and then apparently assuming those `String` contents reference a `path` where the database really is. That's undoubtedly not what you intended.

If `museumDB` was the actual database, usually you'd just open the database directly:

```
internal override init(){
    path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("museumDB", ofType: "")!)
    database = FMDatabase(path: path)

    super.init()
}
```

Or, often you'd see if the database exists in the Documents folder, and if not, copy it from the bundle to Documents folder, but then just open the one in Documents. (E.g. I notice you have a `copyDatabase` method that is attempting to something like that, but you never call this nor open this new copy in Documents.) E.g. you could do something like:

```
func openDatabase() -> Bool {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager() // get the file manager
    let documentsFolder = try! fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
    let documentURL = documentsFolder.URLByAppendingPathComponent("museumDB")
    let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("museumDB", withExtension: nil)!

    var error: NSError?
    if !documentURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error) {
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtURL(bundleURL, toURL: documentURL)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("%@", error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }
    }

    database = FMDatabase(path: documentURL.path)
    return database.open()
}
```

That obviously assumes the database was called `museumDB`. Personally, I'd use a name like `museum.db` or `museum.sqlite`, but that's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: see the updated question i have added the full database loader class

Comment: and yes museumDB is the database file

Comment: Thanks this works now it was the damn swift 2 converters fault